# Logic for a specific Count

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to fill a asp:GridView with a result of a query. My query, has to count the number of ocurrences of a specific status_id IF the column 'san_proposta.credenciada_id' is different of the value 10. If the column 'san_proposta.credenciada_id' is equals of the value 10 in anothers rows, I need count all ocurrences of a specific status_id that has the 'credenciada_id' equal 10.

I'm trying the follow code, but I don't know how to do with this specifics count.

```
SELECT DISTINCT San_Proposta.Imovel_Id, San_Logradouro.Descricao, San_Endereco.Logradouro, San_Imovel.Numero, San_TipoComplemento.Descricao AS Expr1,
San_Imovel.Complemento, San_Imovel.TipoDsc1, San_Transacao.TransacaoSigla, San_Credenciada.Apelido, San_Transacao.Transacao_ID, COUNT(San_Proposta.StatusProposta_Id) AS NumeroProposta
FROM San_Proposta
JOIN San_Imovel
ON San_Proposta.Imovel_Id = San_Imovel.Imovel_Id
JOIN San_Endereco
ON San_Imovel.Endereco_Id = San_Endereco.Endereco_Id
JOIN San_Logradouro
ON San_Endereco.Logradouro_Id = San_Logradouro.Logradouro_Id
JOIN San_TipoComplemento
ON San_Imovel.TipoComplemento_Id = San_TipoComplemento.TipoComplemento_Id
JOIN San_Transacao
ON San_Imovel.Transacao_ID = San_Transacao.Transacao_ID
JOIN San_Credenciada
ON San_Imovel.Credenciada_Id = San_Credenciada.Credenciada_Id
WHERE (San_Imovel.Credenciada_Id = 10 OR San_Proposta.Credenciada_Id = 10)
GROUP BY San_Proposta.Imovel_Id, San_Logradouro.Descricao, San_Endereco.Logradouro, San_Imovel.Numero,
San_TipoComplemento.Descricao, San_Imovel.Complemento, San_Imovel.TipoDsc1, San_Transacao.TransacaoSigla,
San_Credenciada.Apelido, San_Transacao.Transacao_ID, San_Proposta.StatusProposta_Id,
San_Proposta.Credenciada_Id, San_Imovel.Credenciada_Id
ORDER BY San_Proposta.Imovel_Id DESC
```

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results. Reverse engineering a word problem coupled with a query that has `DISTINCT`, `GROUP BY` and `COUNT` is very taxing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you're saying (if I'm interpreting you correctly) it looks like

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN San_Proposta.credenciada_id = 10 THEN San_Proposta.StatusProposta_Id ELSE NULL END)
```

would work for your count.

Comment: Just a style thing really, but I would do SUM(CASE WHEN id = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END).

Comment: Hadn't thought of that one.  I'll keep it in mind.  I love CASE statements :-)